# how to use range slider in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, rangeslider

I am trying to use a range slider widget for my problem. I looked into the net but I couldn't find an example of this widget `RangeSliderH`. I found this library for that. https://pypi.org/project/RangeSlider/

Does anyone know how to update this code to make that show on the screen?currently I am getting this error: `Exception: padX too small, value won't be visible completely, expected padX to be atleast 16.96px`

```
from RangeSlider.RangeSlider import RangeSliderH

from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("750x750")

hVar1 = DoubleVar()  # left handle variable
hVar2 = DoubleVar()  # right handle variable

rs1 = RangeSliderH(root, [hVar1, hVar2], Width=400, Height=60, min_val=0, max_val=400, show_value= True)
rs1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: With your code, I get an error message saying `Exception: padX too small, value won't be visible completely, expected padX to be atleast 16.96px.` If you're getting error messages, please add them to your question. If you're not getting error messages, please make sure that your code doesn't have any error messages that would hinder testing. If this error message is system-specific, don't worry about editing your question.

Comment: yes, I get the same error. Sure, I will update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the suggestion in the exception message to set `padX` to value >= 16.96.

However after fixing it, another exception on `Height` is raised:

```
Exception: Dimensions incompatible, consider decreasing bar_radius or consider increasing widget height, as per given configuration height should be atleast .63.56px.
```

Adjust the value of `Height` as suggested in the exception message as well. So the final fix is:

```py
rs1 = RangeSliderH(root, [hVar1, hVar2], Width=400, Height=65, padX=17, min_val=0, max_val=400, show_value= True)
```